# Error parsing XML file when copying xml code

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to create landscape layout and when I copied a code from my portrait layout I got an error:

error parsing XML:no object found.

This error appears in first line of the code below.

```
**?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#8B4513"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/label1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:background="#2F4F4F"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/rect"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
    <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#8B4513"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/label2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
            android:background="#2F4F4F"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/cm"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/TextField1"
            android:layout_width="110dp"
            android:layout_height="21dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
            android:background="#2F4F4F"
            android:ems="10"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:inputType="text" />
   </LinearLayout>   
    </LinearLayout>**
```

please help

Comment: the very first char is NOT '<'

Comment: I've added "<' and cleaned a project but i;m getting the same error.

Comment: so `**?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>` now looks like `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>`?? you also have `**` at the end of the file (just trying to clean up your XML)

Comment: yes first line looks like this  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> and I have deleted ** but i still get the same error. Thanks for your patience.

Answer (score 0):

**Create a new layout and copy this:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/label1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:background="#2F4F4F"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="hello"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
    <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#8B4513"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/label2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
            android:background="#2F4F4F"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="cm"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/TextField1"
            android:layout_width="110dp"
            android:layout_height="21dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
            android:background="#2F4F4F"
            android:ems="10"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:inputType="text" />
   </LinearLayout>   


</LinearLayout>
```